# tracking facebook install ads

Tags: facebook, mobile, tracking, ads

I want to install the Facebook SDK into my iOS app to track installs from Facebook’s mobile ad units that drive installs.

HOWEVER all the information I’ve read so far is that in order to TRACK the install, the user has to login to Facebook IN THE GAME ITSELF as well.

1. Is this true (please no!!)?
2. If it IS true, is there a way it can be done in the background without the user knowing (legally)?
3. If it isn’t true, how can I set up the ads to be tracked without the ‘second’ login in-game?

This is an education app, and schools/parents are highly unlikely to want to be made to login to facebook within the game itself for security/privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to be logged into is the facebook app, so they can see the ad in the first place.

The ad will show on your newsfeed, and if they click install and follow through, you should have your conversion on first launch of your ios app.

The code to deploy is `[FBSettings publishInstall:@"12345678901234"]` and it goes in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate, which will fire when launched. So unless you're asking for a login in your app before that method fires (such as in `main.m`) you should be fine.

Obviously this thread is rather old, so hopefully you've already solved this.

Comment: How to link that app install to my userID in my database ? so that i can mark my user that it came from facebook Ad ?